# Binding al servicio Soap WsHttpBinding de la Dian

Tags: wcf, binding, app.config

Tengo este App.config pero necesito convertirlo a programación por código, pero no sé que elementos agregar ni como configurarlos para que funcione.

```
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IWcfDianCustomerServices">
      <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
        <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" algorithmSuite="Basic256Sha256Rsa15" establishSecurityContext="false"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Es un servicio Soap 1.2; Tengo esto pero no estoy seguro de ir por el camino correcto:

```
CustomBinding binding = new CustomBinding();
        binding.Name = "WSHttpBinding_IWcfDianCustomerServices";
        SecurityBindingElement security = SecurityBindingElement.CreateAnonymousForCertificateBindingElement();
        TextMessageEncodingBindingElement text = new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement(MessageVersion.Soap12, Encoding.UTF8);
        TransportBindingElement transport = new HttpTransportBindingElement();
        binding.Elements.Add(security);
        binding.Elements.Add(text);
        binding.Elements.Add(transport);
        binding.CreateBindingElements();
```

Por si necesitan saberlo, la configuración del cliente del servicio es este:

```
    <client>
  <endpoint address=" https://vpfe-hab.dian.gov.co/WcfDianCustomerServices.svc " binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IWcfDianCustomerServices" contract="IWcfDianCustomerServices" name="WSHttpBinding_IWcfDianCustomerServices"/>
</client>
```

Comment: estas usando un using? porque no me deja hacer binding.Security.,.. Me tira error. Me dice binding.Security no existe en el contexto actual

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Encontre la respuesta, se hace asi:

```
        WSHttpBinding wSHttpBinding = new WSHttpBinding(SecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential);
        wSHttpBinding.Name = "WSHttpBinding_IWcfDianCustomerServices";
        wSHttpBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.None;
        wSHttpBinding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.Certificate;
        wSHttpBinding.Security.Message.AlgorithmSuite = SecurityAlgorithmSuite.Basic256Sha256Rsa15;
        wSHttpBinding.Security.Message.EstablishSecurityContext = false;
        EndpointAddress endPoint = new EndpointAddress("https://vpfe-hab.dian.gov.co/WcfDianCustomerServices.svc");
       WcfDianCustomerServicesClient Service = new WcfDianCustomerServicesClient(wSHttpBinding, endPoint);
```

Al final hay que agregar un certificado tipo x509Certificate2

```
 Service.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = x509Certificate2;
```